# Kanji and meaning behind Shikifuton?

Tags: etymology

I've been looking at futon recently and there's a particularly kind called the Shikibed or Shiki Futon. I was wondering where this "Shiki" was coming from.

Comment: Did you mean 「[敷布団]{しきぶとん}」?

Comment: Maybe it was anglicized like まきずし.  In America, まきずし was anglicized as "maki sushi", apparently to avoid confusing Americans with rendaku.

Comment: 「敷きベッド」is a new word for me...^^ （もしかして「敷きパッド」のことかな？）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

敷き布団, or "shikibuton" refers to the bottom part of a futon, which traditionally has two parts: the part you lie on and the part that you cover it with, or basically the mattress and the blanket (or duvet if you want to go there). The terms 敷き布団 and 掛け布団 are derived from their purposes. For example, 敷{し}く means to spread or lay something out, so the shikifuton is what you spread on the floor. The 掛け布団 (kakebuton) is what you use to 掛ける, or to "put on" in the sense of adding it on top. The respective kanji, 掛 and 敷, retain these meanings.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Japanese Wikipedia article](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B8%83%E5%9B%A3), the two parts of a futon are the duvet or 掛け布団, and, what @Tony is shopping for, the mattress or 敷き布団.

Cheers.